# Why has my question been marked as CW?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked this question earlier and it's been marked as CW (notably, after the single definitive answer was added):

[How long does it take for an Office 365 app to be approved?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83046/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-office-365-app-to-be-approved)

If the questions was "How long did it take your app to be approved?" or similar I'd understand, but it seems like an odd decision. Especially given the timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have listened to you and I hear you. The answer seems to be that there is no answer. Your post is unmarked as wiki :)

Comment: Based on the large number of answers?...

Comment: Based on this sentence: "This unfortunately is a how long is a piece of string question" - meaning that the question does not have on finite answer, and was of risk of being closed for being primarily opinion based for example. That the person answering you also felt this was the case builds on that feeling

Comment: Maybe it was a bad call, I honestly don't know. What I feel though is that now this post can serve as a base where people can collaborate around the whole submission / approval process. But, as you know, I'm very new as moderator and therefore very humble about that errors will be made. Hopefully you have been in a similar situation and understand our difficulties

Comment: I think we would need other users / mods opinions to come any further though :)

Comment: As mod it is paramount to keep the insight you have by means of your super-powers secret for normal users! People are told that flagging and voting is anonymous, so please don't reveal *any* information regarding userswithou carefully considering the implications.This also is the case when resolving disputes between users where we also wan tto keep things as anonymous as possible. Regarding the specific Q i say it is ok to keep it non-CW as there is one answer, that there is no answer ;)

Comment: @AndersRask, message received!  It was not my intention to harm anyone, and I will surely think more about privacy of reporters in the future

Comment: (pssst! it was me that upvoted that comment;))